# Prevent Mediawiki software from printing link URLs

Tags: mediawiki

I have a MediaWiki instance with a lot of templates. Sometimes I create pages which use templates and create many external links, giving me a clickable checklist.

However, when I print such a list, the MediaWiki software prints the URL of every single external link, cluttering the hardcopy with useless text:
I'm not interested in "link-text (https://my.stunning.site/the/very/lengthy/url)" but only in "link-text".

Is there some magic word or even configuration setting to help me to get a "clean" hardcopy?  Thank you!

(MediaWiki 1.25.2, pretty basic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's set up [in the print stylesheet](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki/blob/1.25.2/resources/src/mediawiki.legacy/commonPrint.css#L173-L183). You can add something like

```
.mediawiki .mw-body a.external.text:after,
.mediawiki .mw-body a.external.autonumber:after {
    content: none;
}
```

in your own stylesheet to override it.

Comment: Sorry I missed your answer for such a long time; this looks promising.
I just couldn't make it work yet ...
With `monobook` being chosen, the stylesheet should be `.../wiki/User:Myname/monobook.css`, right?

Comment: If you only want to change it for your own user (and per-user stylesheets are [enabled](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgAllowUserCss)) then yes.

Comment: Ok; seems the `$wgAllowUserCss` setting is missing in the LocalSettings.php. I'll need to wait for my colleague to return for this, because I don't have administration access to the server...